# facebook login button callback manager

Tags: android, facebook

I am new to programming in general, but I am learing by doing.
Trying to follow tutorials and how-to's to learn whats what.

I wish to use facebook login in my app, but i am having a hard time getting it to work. Possibly because i don't really understand it.

I am trying to put the facebook login button in a empty project just to play around with it and learn.

The problem i am having is that callbackmanager is red in code.

my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.langaard.facebooktest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```

error messages are:
Error:(22, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable callbackManager
Error:(23, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable view
Error:(24, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable callbackManager
Error:(62, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable callbackManager

I'm shure this is an easy fix and I'm just not seeing it, but would appreciate your help.

Thanks.
Rune.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared CallbackManager and you're using it. Declare it inside your class before you use it in any method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//declaration was missing here
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Now you can use it here
```

Answer (score 0):

**Intitalize Facebook SDK before set content view.**

Change here.

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And Also you need to declare variable for callbackmanager.

**Do this.**

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

your `callback` object isn't declared, add

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    ....
}
```